# Why is my ggplot2 map misreading input latitude and longitude data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, geom-point, ggspatial

I am trying to add city points and labels to a ggplot2 map, and when I add a geom_point() layer to the map with a specified points drawn from a newly created dataframe with specified latitude and longitude, it outputs points and labels at different latitudes and longitudes than the ones specified. This is the code, and when the map outputs the points are at lat: 26.00 and long:33.00, and the map is distorted. When I take off the geom_point() and geom_text layers the scale of the map returns to what it should be. [distorted map output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LwQ4.png)

```
city_data <- data.frame(city_name=c("Beit Hanina"))
city_data$lat <- c(31.8400)
city_data$lon <- c(35.2200)

ggplot(data = ejru) + 
  geom_sf()+
  geom_point(data = city_data, mapping = aes(x = lon, y = lat), colour = "red") +
  geom_text(data = city_data, mapping=aes(x=lon, y=lat, label=city_name), nudge_y = 0.5,           color="darkblue")
```

I have tried several different strings of code to add points, and either the points simply don't show up or they are distorted as they are in this case.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How did you create the `ejru` object? What packages do you have loaded?

Comment: The most likely problem is that `ejru` has a co-ordinate reference system that is specified in metres of Easting & Westing rather than degrees latitude and longitude. You could try adding `+ coord_sf(crs = "WGS84")` to your plot, which should transform to the appropriate projection. You haven't given us enough information to be certain of the problem though (we have no idea what the coordinate reference system for `ejru` is, because we don't have this object). You can confirm by running `st_crs(ejru)`

Comment: Thanks to you both. Allan, adding coord_sf(crs="WGS84) didn't fix it but it got me on the right track and I figured it out. I changed the reference system for the EJRU object outside of the ggplot map code and then ran the code again. I'm a newbie to posting on stackoverflow, but next time I'll be sure to add more information. Many thanks!